# How to add playback speeds in exo player custom ui

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x

I integrated Exo-player with custom UI. Everything is working fine but now i need to add playback speed controls in the UI. Can any one give references for adding it...!

Answer (score 2):

i don't know this answer is correct or not but i used this approach
since i'm using my own custom UI. I added one more button on my custom UI and i created a custom popup with playback options whatever i needed based on the response i'm setting the playback speed

```
simpleExoPlayer.playWhenReady = false
val alertDialog: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
        alertDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.playback_speed))
        val items = arrayOf("0.5x", "0.75x", "Normal(1x)", "1.25x", "1.5x")
        val checkedItem = playbackPosition
        alertDialog.setSingleChoiceItems(items, checkedItem, DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, pos ->
            when (pos) {
                0 -> simpleExoPlayer.setPlaybackParameters(PlaybackParameters(0.5f))
                1 -> simpleExoPlayer.setPlaybackParameters(PlaybackParameters(0.75f))
                2 -> simpleExoPlayer.setPlaybackParameters(PlaybackParameters(1f))
                3 -> simpleExoPlayer.setPlaybackParameters(PlaybackParameters(1.25f))
                4 -> simpleExoPlayer.setPlaybackParameters(PlaybackParameters(1.5f))
            }
            playbackPosition=pos
        })
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok",DialogInterface.OnClickListener{ dialog, i ->
            simpleExoPlayer.playWhenReady = true
            dialog.dismiss()
        })
        val alert: AlertDialog = alertDialog.create()
        alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
        alert.show()
```